# Source for kissing an aron

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, kissing, ark-aron-kodesh

I've seen people kiss an *aron kodesh* (cabinet holding Torah scrolls) when they approach it and, if they were standing near it, before they leave it. Does this have any written source; or, are there known instances of authoritative individuals' having done (or advised) thus?

Comment: Inspired by the comments on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9469.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35429

Answer (score 6):

In Shivat Tzion it says to kiss the WALLS of the Shul because of their holiness, and I say Kal WaHomer the Aron.

Answer (score -1):

There are sources for kissing a mezuza, such as:

> [לפיכך, כשיצא אדם מפתח ביתו, ינשק המזוזה: [חיי אדם, חלק א' כלל ט"ו

And possibly the custom of kissing a sefer Torah stems from this.

Comment: The question asks about the aron, not the sefer torah.

Comment: @Monica presumably the custom of kissing the Aron is a further extension.

Comment: I don't see a correlation. Esp. with the quote that refers to what people should do when they leave their home. Any correlation to this quote seems considerably weakened by the fact that shuls don't require a mezuzah.