# Should women kiss the Torah with their hand or with a prayer book?

Tags: minhag, women, torah-service, sefer-torah, niddah

When the Torah comes around in shul, is it preferable for women to touch it with their hand (and then kiss their hand) or with their prayer book (and then kiss their prayer book)?

Presumably some women avoid using their hands because of the issue of niddah--but isn't everyone always "ritually impure" these days anyway? (After all, that's one reason we don't touch the actual Torah, but only the cover.)

I know there are minhags to do it both ways, so please bring authoritative sources for your position.

Comment: I'm also wondering what unmarried men use to kiss the Torah. (I've never been able to see it from the women's side...)

Comment: [She should walk along after it if she wishes to honor it, not cover it with saliva.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35431/759)

Comment: I wasn't aware impurity had anything to do with why we don't touch the parchment itself. The prohibition of doing so is recorded in [Megilah 32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=32&format=pdf) and seems to be related to not disgracing the scroll.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've never seen anyone actually kiss the Torah cover; one touches it with one's hand (or book) and then kisses that.

Comment: I wouldn't think that possibly being niddah would affect it, as (I've read) you can't *pasul* a *sefer torah* that way -- and this isn't even the sefer itself but the cover.  Also, as you note, men can be *tamei* too.

Comment: Where is the halocho brought down to kiss a torah? No where

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've heard that the niddah explanation is something that circulates in seminaries, though I too have heard it refuted.

Comment: @SAH Regarding "_I've never seen anyone actually kiss the Torah cover_ ....." -- I have. It happens all the time in most places I daven.

Comment: If I recall correctly, one of the poskim in Yeshiva University suggested that no one should kiss or touch the Torah, or kiss Chumashim or Sidurim because of the danger of bacteria and viri / infection. I think he may have included not shaking hands, as well. I don't recall the Rav's name, though.

Comment: @DanF If you find that, please tell me. I'd love to quote that to all the people who sneeze, pick their noses, etc in shul and then want to shake hands.

Comment: @Scimonster - You don't need a Rav for that. As the average TV med. pill ad would say ... "Ask your doctor if shaking hands is right for you..."

Comment: @DanF "We may ignore the doctors' advice." - Rav Kanievski.

Comment: @Scimonster - I recommend that Rav Kanievski obtain a 2nd opinion.

Comment: @DanF "...if your heart is healthy enough for handshaking"

Comment: @Shokhet I assume you're talking about the men's side? You're saying that some men kiss the Torah cover directly instead of using their talleisim/tzitzis?

Comment: SAH Yes [15 char]

Comment: Some related links: [This shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/764155) (starting ~7:45) and [this article](http://www.shalhevetboilingpoint.com/torah/2011/11/03/tradition-may-rule-but-law-says-girls-can-carry-torah/). More generally: [here](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=524), [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2010/07/25/kissing-the-torah/), [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3017), [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_kissing_the_mezuzah/), and [here](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5761/shelech.html).

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov See the Rama at the end of Siman 149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ha Rav Riskin](http://media.ots.org.il/features/q&a5.htm) mentioned the following, in regard to a somewhat different question on women's minyanim.

> There are some authorities - including my teacher and mentor, Rav Soloveitchik ztz"l - who maintain that **since a Sefer Torah cannot become "tamei" (ritually impure),** a woman may also read from a Sefer Torah, but without the order of aliyot and berakhot since these were instituted for men only.

(bold emphasis added)

Therefore, any tamei person, male or female, may kiss / touch a Torah scroll's cover, and there is no halachically preferred way to do so (directly, or with a book or other object).

Comment: Can the scroll's cover become impure?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know, but why would it matter?  The scroll can't become tamei, so it can have a tamei cover on it.  In any case, we see that men aren't required to immerse in a mikvah before holding or touching a Torah, covered or not.

Comment: Maybe it's degrading to the Torah? (Im not saying it is or isnt, just that would seem to be the primary concern and this answer hasnt addressed it at all)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16685/discussion-between-jake-and-double-aa).

Comment: How do you know neither is preferred just because both are permitted?

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with your last comment. But as for "degrading to the Torah"--what on earth could that/would that mean? And why would it "seem to be" the primary concern? I can't imagine that being a serious concern in any but the most fanatical communities.

Comment: @DoubleAA ...And what of "degrading to women"??

Comment: @DoubleAA --OK, sorry. Perhaps you meant "having the scroll be ritually impure [would be] degrading to the Torah"?

Comment: @SAH You don't think Torah degradation is the relevant factor in every community in determining how to touch it? What other factor do you think is at play?

Comment: "degrading to women" What about it? Do you think it comes into play here? Why?

Comment: $DoubleAA if you are saying that a niddah's touching the Torah [cover] would be degrading to the Torah, this to me sounds like a degradation of women. Even married women are niddah approximately 40% of the time (and nearly 100% of unmarried women are niddah 100% of the time). It is a very normal state of womanhood. The idea that a Torah scroll is "higher" than a human being and needs protection from them just seems wrong to me.

Comment: @SAH I didn't see your ping till just now. I don't know what normal has to do with it. Sexual intercourse with ejaculation is also quite normal (and often recommended!), yet one cannot enter the Temple after doing so. Is that offensive to men? Is it wrong that the Temple has such restrictions? The idea that there are certain conditions (whether temporary or permanent) which affect one's ability to perform certain ritual actions is one which is foundational to Judaism. I don't know why you feel a need to harp on this one as particularly problematic. No one is blaming the women for menstruating.

Comment: @DoubleAA But we're not talking about entering the Temple, we're talking about touching a Torah cover with one's body. And that men are obviously allowed to do.

Comment: @sah I don't follow you're point. Why is one offensive and one not? Different conditions have different ramifications. OK. No big deal.

Comment: Incidentally, it's possible a Boel Niddah cannot. I'm not sure.