# Following a sefer Torah

Tags: torah-service, ark-aron-kodesh, opening-the-ark

In a minyan I participate in, the one doing hachnasas sefer torah has to return the torah immediately to an aron kodesh in another room. I see people walk out the door to follow the Torah outside of the room (and presumably walking it down the hall) as the person carrying the Torah exits.

Is there a halachah for this practice, or is it just a praiseworthy minhag to make sure the Torah is escorted (which I thought I understood one does for his Rav if he encounters him walking alone)?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35431/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you. Regarding the linked answer; how does it apply if it has to be transported to another room? I notice usually only one person follows and not everyone ( like the Rema states). Do you know if/where the other halachah is for doing the same for one's Rav and do the same gedarim apply there?