# Two seforim being taken out

Tags: tefilla, torah-service

How should two Sifrei Torah be taken out of the ark since one should not do two mitvot simultaneously? Should one person take them both out and give one to the chazzan and then keep one for himself or should one person hand a Sefer Torah to the chazzan and then retrieve the second Sefer Torah? Alternatively, should two separate individuals each simultaneously remove both sifrei Torah at the same time?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9469

Comment: -1 How is this two separate mitzvot?  How is this even a mitzvah at all?

Comment: something to consider is we take out more than one sefer torah on days when there are readings from more than one location in the Torah so to not cause tircha tsibur by keeping everyone waiting while the gabbai scrolls to the next place for leining

Comment: what is your source for not doing two mitzvot simultaneously? Also leining isn't a mitzvah.

Answer (score 0):

Our minhag is two people come up.  The first person opens the ark, takes out the first Torah, hands it to the chazen, then he takes out the second Torah and hands it to the second person who came up. The first person then closes the ark.

Comment: As I wrote this first person is doing two mitsvot 'chavilos' and therefore my third method would be preferable.